# Ruby: open textfile and take lines as string arguments

Tags: ruby

Here is my Code:

```
if ARGV.length != 1
    puts "We need exactly one parameter. The name of a file."
    exit;
end

filename = ARGV[0]
puts "Going to open '#{filename}'"

fh = open filename

fh.each do |line|
    HID_num(line)
end

fh.close
def HID_num(str)
    temp = str.split(" ")
    temp.map do |element|
        matches = element.match(/\A[A-Z]{4}(\d{8})\z/)
        next unless matches
        matches[1]
    end.compact
end
```

So my issue here is that I need to open any `textfile.txt` and go to the terminal call `ruby example.rb textfile.txt` It should print the valid strings only.

My issue is I cannot seem to make it work. Could anyone help out?

Comment: Which bit doesn't work? Do you get an error message?

Comment: @SagarPandya Hi! So it is as if the HID_num(line) does not work. It only prints  the Going to open filename

Comment: you never call the method you define. Could that be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You are really close.

First, you have forgotten the **puts** method while invoking HID_num, to print the output.

Next, define the method before invoking it. The Ruby in default flavour is interpreted. Else you run into the *NoMethodError*.

Finally, to get the actual matched substrings alone to be printed, **try map! instead of map** method. It overwrites the array of original strings with the matched substring, thereby retaining the matches.

```
    temp.map! do |element|
        matches = element.match(/\A[A-Z]{4}(\d{8})\z/)
        next unless matches
        matches[1]
    end.compact
```

Comment: Oh I see! Now it is printing but it has a lot of empty lines between the print out...

Comment: Could happen when there are no matches. Just check for nil before printing

Comment: Share your sample input and expected output